# Capturing (1x Only) HTTP POST Request [tcpdump]

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, http, packet, sniffing

Every now and then;
I like to fire up `tcpdump` and just watch the network traffic as the packets flow on by.

*For example:*

```
user@host:~$ sudo tcpdump -Aevvv
```

Will parse & print all local network-traffic to the standard output, in real time, instead of writing (saving) to file. It's great for taking a quick glimpse at what's happening on the local network.

It's not uncommon to find packets coming through in larger quantities/at higher speeds than what is comfortable to parse and/or read. In such cases, I usually indicate a desired target host like so:

```
user@host:~$ sudo tcpdump -Aevvv host security.stackexchange.com
```

Obviously, the desired target host in this example is `security.stackexchange.com`. This is for no reason other than being the first to come to mind and can, of course, be set to any host you like. Using the `host` filter can clean up the results quite nicely, but I would like to take it one step further and specify certain **HTTP** **Web Request** types such as **HEAD, GET, POST**, & so on.

To continue in the spirit of our example, I would like to specify a `tcpdump` packet-filter rule for capturing **HTTP POST Requests;** so as to demonstrate what's happening behind the scenes when submitting content to a remote host like `security.stackexchange.com`.

So that is my question: ***(When using `tcpdump`..)***
***How can I specify a filter for POST Request packets only?***

Answer (score 3):

You can't for various reasons:

- tcpdump has no idea of application level protocols.
- That this is a TCP connection containing a POST is only known after the TCP handshake is already done, that is you either would loose the connection setup or you would need to capture everything and store it somewhere in case it might turn out to be a POST later.
- There can be multiple HTTP requests inside a TCP connection and the POST might not be the first one.

Note that you might try to capture only the packets starting with "POST" as proposed in a different answer. But, this will capture also other packets starting with POST (and not only the POST requests), will not capture the payload in most cases (only if it is really small and contained in the same package) and will not capture the response.

Instead I recommend to capture all the traffic which might contain a POST and then later filter the captured traffic using wireshark/tshark, see https://serverfault.com/questions/309515/how-to-make-wireshark-filter-post-requests-only

Comment: There's also a command line version you called t-shark. You can find more info on it here: http://kvz.io/blog/2010/05/15/analyze-http-requests-with-tshark/

Comment: But I also -1 because you can filter with tcpdump :)

Comment: @LucasKauffman: tshark (not t-shark!) is actually mentioned in my answer and the filter with tcpdump has the problems I've added in the comment to your response.

Comment: ooooh, can you edit your question a bit so I can upvote :)

Comment: maybe embed my answer and then explain why it won't work, then I'll remove mine.

Comment: @LucasKauffman: done

Comment: Surely, there must be a way to filter POST requests.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, "Note that you might try to capture only the packets starting with ***"POST"***". Well that sounds suitable, right? I do use Wireshark sometimes, btw. It's too unstable and resource intensive for my taste. I mean, it's great; I like it a lot, a CLI just fits better with my workflow more often than not.

Comment: @tjt263: As I've written you might capture other things and you might not capture the full payload and you don't get the response this way. If you can live with these restrictions it is a lightweight option. And if you like the capabilities of wireshark but prefer the CLI simply use tshark.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, So.. `tshark` is compatible with `wireshark` filters, like `http.request.method == "POST"`?

Comment: @tjt263: yes, tshark is the command line version of wireshark. For more info please see [the documentation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Very nice.